# Creating a new variable by comparing others

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that consists of a series of readings made by different people/instruments, of a bunch of different dimensions. It looks like this:

```
SUBJECT DIM1_1 DIM1_2 DIM1_3 DIM1_4 DIM1_5 DIM2_1 DIM2_2 DIM2_3 DIM3_1 DIM3_2
1       1      .      1      1      2      3      3      3      2      .
2       1      1      .      1      1      2      2      3      1      1
3       2      2      2      .      .      1      .      .      5      5
...     ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
```

My real dataset contains around 190 dimensions, with up to 5 measures in each one

I have to obey a set of rules to create a new variable for each dimension:

- If there are 2 different values in the same dimension (missings excluded), the new variable is a missing.
- If all values are the same (missings excluded), the new variable assumes the same value.

My new variables should look like this:

```
SUBJECT  ...  DIM1_X DIM2_X DIM3_X
1        ...  .      3      2
2        ...  1      .      1
3        ...  2      1      5
```

The problem here is that i don't have the same number of measures for each dimension. Also, i could only come up with a lot of IF's (and I mean a LOT, as more measures in a given dimension increases the number of comparisons), so I wonder if there is some easier way to handle this particular problem.

Any help would be apreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to transpose it to vertical (one row per DIMx_y), summarize, then set the ones you want missing to missing, then retranspose (and if needed merge back on).

```
data have;
input SUBJECT DIM1_1 DIM1_2 DIM1_3 DIM1_4 DIM1_5 DIM2_1 DIM2_2 DIM2_3 DIM3_1 DIM3_2;
datalines;
1       1      .      1      1      2      3      3      3      2      .
2       1      1      .      1      1      2      2      3      1      1
3       2      2      2      .      .      1      .      .      5      5
;;;;
run;

data have_pret;
set have;
array dim_data DIM:;
do _t = 1 to dim(dim_Data); *dim function is not related to the name - it gives # of vars in array;
 dim_Group = scan(vname(dim_data[_t]),1,'_');
 dim_num =  input(scan(vname(dim_data[_t]),2,'_'),BEST12.);
 dim_val=dim_data[_t];
 output;
end;
keep dim_group dim_num subject dim_val;
run; 

proc freq data=have_pret noprint;
by subject dim_group;
tables dim_val/out=want_pret(where=(not missing(dim_val)));
run;

data want_pret2;
set want_pret;
by subject dim_Group;
if percent ne 100 then dim_val=.;
idval = cats(dim_Group,'_X');
if last.dim_Group;
run;

proc transpose data=want_pret2 out=want;
by subject;
id idval;
var dim_val;
run;
```